# Tron fullnode disk space limit for leveldb database

Tags: configuration, blockchain, tron

Good day. I have config.conf file as config for TRON Fullnode.jar version GreatVoyage-v4.7.1.1(Pittacus). I'm use the lite mode in fullnode. I have 2 problems:

1. How I can limit disk space for tron fullnode database (leveldb format) to 50GB maximum?
2. For today I have 94GB database, how I can clear their to 50GB? An example I can clear all lines and save only all created in the last 20 days. How I can do this?
   I don't fined the solution in original documentation, bot I know the variant for solve must be always.

I'm use this configuration for my database in the config.conf file:

```
storage {
  db.version = 2,
  db.engine = "LEVELDB",
  db.sync = false,
  db.directory = "/tron-database",
  index.directory = "/tron-index",
  transHistory.switch = "off",

  #default = {
  #  maxOpenFiles = 100
  #}
  #defaultM = {
  #  maxOpenFiles = 500
  #}
  #defaultL = {
  #  maxOpenFiles = 1000
  #}

  properties = [
    # {
    #   name = "account",
    #   path = "storage_directory_test",
    #   createIfMissing = true,
    #   paranoidChecks = true,
    #   verifyChecksums = true,
    #   compressionType = 1,        # compressed with snappy
    #   blockSize = 4096,           # 4  KB =         4 * 1024 B
    #   writeBufferSize = 10485760, # 10 MB = 10 * 1024 * 1024 B
    #   cacheSize = 10485760,       # 10 MB = 10 * 1024 * 1024 B
    #   maxOpenFiles = 100
    # },
    # {
    #   name = "account-index",
    #   path = "storage_directory_test",
    #   createIfMissing = true,
    #   paranoidChecks = true,
    #   verifyChecksums = true,
    #   compressionType = 1,        # compressed with snappy
    #   blockSize = 4096,           # 4  KB =         4 * 1024 B
    #   writeBufferSize = 10485760, # 10 MB = 10 * 1024 * 1024 B
    #   cacheSize = 10485760,       # 10 MB = 10 * 1024 * 1024 B
    #   maxOpenFiles = 100
    # },
  ]

  needToUpdateAsset = true

  # dbsettings is needed when using rocksdb as the storage implement (db.version=2 and db.engine="ROCKSDB").
  # we'd strongly recommend that do not modify it unless you know every item's meaning clearly.
  dbSettings = {
    levelNumber = 7
    # compactThreads = 32
    blocksize = 64  # n * KB
    maxBytesForLevelBase = 256  # n * MB
    maxBytesForLevelMultiplier = 10
    level0FileNumCompactionTrigger = 4
    targetFileSizeBase = 256  # n * MB
    targetFileSizeMultiplier = 1
  }

  # backup settings when using rocks db as the storage implement (db.version=2 and db.engine="ROCKSDB").
  # if you want to use the backup plugin, please confirm set the db.version=2 and db.engine="ROCKSDB" above.
  backup = {
    enable = true  # indicate whether enable the backup plugin
    propPath = "prop.properties" # record which bak directory is valid
    bak1path = "/tron-backup/database" # you must set two backup directories to prevent application halt unexpected(e.g. kill -9).
    bak2path = "/tron-backup2/database"
    frequency = 1000   # indicate backup db once every 10000 blocks processed.
  }
}
```